# LiveCharts: Show chart title in windows form

Tags: c#, winforms, charts, livecharts

I want to show **Title** of the chart using LiveCharts in Windows Forms.

I am unable to find **Title** property on the chart control, I have also gone through the documentation and found WPF related example only. So, I tried setting **Text** property of the chart itself but could not find it working.

Any idea, how can I set chart title?

Comment: That question was about properly exporting chart title to image/pdf.

Comment: the answer describes solely how to draw a title on the chart itself. Even in the question OP writes: "**so the title needs to be on the chart itself.**". I agree that the answer is a little overhead, but apparently this is the way to get a title in it. But if you think that the answer is useless, I can retract my close vote

Comment: I don't think the answer is useless. 
However, I am expecting some more cleaner, straight forward and appropriate approach of setting title. Because in that answer, title is not being set on chart itself but another table layout control is used to control its styling and visibility.

Comment: you could also ask directly [the main author](https://gitter.im/beto-rodriguez/Live-Charts) of [live chart](https://lvcharts.net). Good luck :)

Comment: ahh but I see you did it already ;)